# in python, how do i split a number by the decimal point

Tags: python, floating-point, split, decimal

So if I run:

```
a = b / c
```

and get the result `1.2234`

How do i separate it so that I have:

```
a = 1
b = 0.2234
```

Answer (score 22):

```
>>> from math import modf
>>> b,a = modf(1.2234)
>>> print ('a = %f and b = %f'%(a,b))
a = 1.000000 and b = 0.223400
>>> b,a = modf(-1.2234)
>>> print ('a = %f and b = %f'%(a,b))
a = -1.000000 and b = -0.223400
```

Answer (score 11):

```
a,b = divmod(a, 1)
```

Comment: For `a = -1.7` the result is `-2` and `0.3`, which is probably not what the author wanted to get.

Comment: i wont have negative numbers involved.

Comment: Note that using the constant `1.0` will be slightly more efficient, as otherwise `divmod()` will have to do an integer-to-float conversion with every single call.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
a, b = int(a), a - int(a)
```

Bonus: works for negative numbers as well.  `-1.7` is split into `-1` and `-0.7` instead of `-2` and `0.3`.

**EDIT** If `a` is guaranteed to be non-negative, then gnibbler's solution is the way to go.

**EDIT 2** IMHO, Odomontois' solution beats both mine and gnibbler's.

Answer (score 1):

```
b = a % 1
a = int(a)
```

or something

Comment: For `a = -1.7` the result is `-2` and `0.3`, which is probably not what the author wanted to get.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in different ways:
1.With inbuilt function:

```
def fractional_part(numerator, denominator):
    if denominator != 0:
        return math.modf(numerator/denominator)
    return 0
```

2.Without inbuilt function:

```
def fractional_part(numerator, denominator):
    if denominator != 0:
        a = str(numerator/denominator).split(".")[0]
        b = "0." + str(numerator/denominator).split(".")[1]
        return (float(a),float(b))
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int(a)/b == 1
(a/b)%1 == 0.2234
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 1.2234

y = str(x/100).split('.')

a = y[0]
b = y[1]
```

---

then the result is...

```
a = 1
b = 2234
```

Comment: b = 2234 is not what OP wished. He want b = 0.2234

Answer (score 0):

You can use also numpy function [np.modf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.modf.html):

```
fractional_part, int_part = np.modf([0,1.2234,3.5])
```

Of course, this is efficient if you can deal with vectors instead of single numbers one by one.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest method but it has a flaw that the numbers you'd get after execution will not be reduced but rather in their complete form

```
x = 1.2234 
#x = a/b

a, b = x.as_integer_ratio()
print(a)
print(b)
```

like, the a, b in this case are 5509703784125065 and 4503599627370496 respectively