# How to get numbers after decimal point?

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal

How do I get the numbers after a decimal point?

For example, if I have `5.55`, how do i get `.55`?

Comment: Related: [In Python how do I split a number by the decimal point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454085/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-number-by-the-decimal-point)

Comment: I think you should change the accepted answer on this. I almost didn't scroll down to the x10 times voted answer, and this would have bitten me later.

Comment: I think this is a simple approach: `float( '0.' + str(5.55).split('.')[1] )`  >>> 0.55. But if someone thinks different, please let me know.

Comment: I don't understand why we need all these complex solutions, a simple 
float_num = 5.55
dec_Num  = float_num - int(float_num)
what am I missing here?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

An easy approach for you:

```
number_dec = str(number-int(number))[1:]
```

Comment: Exercise for the reader: make it work for numbers larger than or equal to 10

Comment: If you want to omit decimal point then simply do this `number_dec = str(n-int(n))[2:]`

Comment: `number_dec = str(number-int(number)).split('.')[1]`

Comment: @intuited I was confused by your comment- this answer should work fine for numbers over 2 digits. You wont run into floating point issues until 2^14 (16384) for 2 decimal places, 2^13 (8192) for 3 decimal places, and so on.

Comment: Downvote because this is an unnecessarily complicated approach. The answer I sought was the next answer, `5.55 % 1`, which is also a more generally useful answer--one can use the modulo division approach in multiple languages, whereas the above answer is Python-specific.

Comment: **NOTE:** This solution returns a string including the dot (``.55``), which you may not expect due the questions title!

Comment: @intuited still looking for that solution? any idea

Comment: String based solutions are horrible if performance is important for your app.

Comment: @Anthony Vallone answer is cleaner and correct approach

Comment: `str(5.55 - int(5.55))[1:]` returns `.5499999999999998` instead of the `.55` mentioned in the question.

Comment: The shortest and correct answer is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48463863/8928024). The solution posted here is regardless of float/int subtracting **"*number - number*"** and result in null or zeros or 0.0!

Comment: This is a real bad practice. Shouldn't be recommended as the accepted answer.

Comment: Another reason this is bad: I'm european, and here str will give 5,55 (we use comma). So the code is also needlessly restricted to american users.

Comment: Download because this is an unnecessarily complicated approach despite having simpler method.

Answer (score 283):

```
5.55 % 1
```

Keep in mind this won't help you with floating point rounding problems. I.e., you may get:

```
0.550000000001
```

Or otherwise a little off the 0.55 you are expecting.

Comment: As for `modf`, it can screw the precision as well: `math.modf(5.55)` will return (0.5499999999999998, 5.0).

Comment: does anyone know which would be the faster operation,  this method described above,  or: float b = a - int(a)  ?  i suspect the later, but wanted to see if there was confirmation

Comment: On a Raspberry Pi this method `x%1` was almost twice as fast as the `x-int(x)` and `modf(x)[0]` methods (the timings were 980ns, 1.39us, and 1.47us averaged over 1000000 runs). My value for `x` was always positive so I did not have to worry about that.

Comment: Definitely the module operation is faster. It doesn't have to do any name lookups. Whereas calling the int function does a lookup on the global variables.

Comment: fancy not just having a frac()

Comment: This works perfectly, but could anyone explain why it works?

Comment: The % operator is the modulo operator, and rather than explain it in great detail here, I'll link an article instead. https://www.jquery-az.com/python-modulo/

Comment: Beware this breaks on negative numbers.

Comment: @M.Lautaro Just take the absolute value of the input before doing the modulus. It's a little slower, but still faster then using `math.modf` solution.

Comment: `round(5.55 % 1,2)`

Comment: @eric .5 is a special case. With `-2.25 % 1` for example, the result is `0.75`.

Comment: @wjandrea yikes! Deleted my comment so as not to mislead people -- I use `math.modf()` solution now it gets it right in all cases.

Answer (score 204):

Use [modf](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.modf):

```
>>> import math
>>> frac, whole = math.modf(2.5)
>>> frac
0.5
>>> whole
2.0
```

Comment: Good solution, but, `math.modf(2.53) = (0.5299999999999998, 2.0)` expected answer is 0.53

Comment: @LordLoh. that's because of floating point rounding, and will happen with any method.

Comment: @LordLoh. Try to use round(0.5299999999999998 , 2) to get 0.53  Another way is to use Decimal from decimal package. https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: @Rena More precisely: "... and will happen for any method where the result has to be given as an IEEE 754 double-precision float."

Answer (score 83):

What about:

```
a = 1.3927278749291
b = a - int(a)

b
>> 0.39272787492910011
```

Or, using numpy:

```
import numpy
a = 1.3927278749291
b = a - numpy.fix(a)
```

Answer (score 43):

Using the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module from the standard library, you can retain the original precision and avoid floating point rounding issues:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('4.20') % 1
Decimal('0.20')
```

As [kindall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416467/kindall) [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886402/python-how-to-get-numbers-after-decimal-point/3886439#comment-4138283) in the comments, you'll have to convert native `float`s to strings first.

Comment: For the benefit of the original question-asker: floats must be converted to a strings before they can be converted to Decimals.  So if you have `n = 5.55`, n is a float, and you should do `Decimal(str(n)) % 1` to get the fractional part. (This isn't necessary if you have an integer, but it doesn't hurt.)

Comment: @intuited: It doesn't need to be decimal, it works also for float: `10.0/3 % 1` at least on my system

Comment: You can use from_float instead of using a string. d = Decimal.from_float(1.2)

Comment: @intuited How does one obtain the decimal part as an integer? I have tried to_integer() methods but the type is still Decimal.

Comment: @MatthewPurdon - If you use `Decimal.from_float(1.2)` (which can now be written as `Decimal(1.2)`) you will have rounding issues, which this answer was trying to avoid.

Comment: @D1X Now `math.floor` and `math.ceil` will return an `int` when used on a `decimal.Decimal` object. I think this is one of the things that changed between Python 2 and 3. E.g. `math.floor(decimal.Decimal('4.90'))` returns `4`, `math.floor(decimal.Decimal('-4.90'))` returns `-5` and `type(math.floor(decimal.Decimal('-4.90')))` is `<class 'int'>`

Answer (score 10):

Try Modulo:

```
5.55%1 = 0.54999999999999982
```

Answer (score 10):

To make it work with both positive and negative numbers:
try  `abs(x)%1`. For negative numbers, without with `abs`, it will go wrong.

`5.55 % 1`

output 0.5499999999999998

`-5.55 % 1`

output 0.4500000000000002

Answer (score 7):

```
import math
orig = 5.55
whole = math.floor(orig)    # whole = 5.0
frac = orig - whole         # frac = 0.55
```

Comment: >>> frac
0.5499999999999998

Answer (score 5):

similar to the accepted answer, even easier approach using strings would be

```
def number_after_decimal(number1):
    number = str(number1)
    if 'e-' in number: # scientific notation
        number_dec = format(float(number), '.%df'%(len(number.split(".")[1].split("e-")[0])+int(number.split('e-')[1])))
    elif "." in number: # quick check if it is decimal
        number_dec = number.split(".")[1]
    return number_dec
```

Comment: `number = 5.55; "." in number` gives `TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable`. And what would you do if `number = 1e-5`?

Comment: @mark the question is How do I get the numbers after a decimal point? so user is expecting float in decimal notation (not scientific notation), I've added a block for scientific notation too

Comment: A number is a number; it's only _representations_ of a number that might be in scientific notation. So "float in decimal notation" doesn't make much sense here; by the time Python sees it, it's just a `float`; Python doesn't keep any knowledge of what format it was originally expressed in. My `number = 1e-5` example applies equally well to `number = 0.00001`: the `str` representation of the number is in scientific notation. You'll want to deal with `e+` as well as `e-`, by the way.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> n=5.55
>>> if "." in str(n):
...     print "."+str(n).split(".")[-1]
...
.55
```

Comment: This is OK for garden-variety numbers, but doesn't work so well for numbers large (or small) enough to require scientific notation.

Answer (score 4):

Just using simple operator **division '/'** and **floor division '//'** you can easily get the fraction part of any given float.

```
number = 5.55

result = (number/1) - (number//1)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution I tried:

```
num = 45.7234
(whole, frac) = (int(num), int(str(num)[(len(str(int(num)))+1):]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes trailing zeros matter

```
In [4]: def split_float(x):
   ...:     '''split float into parts before and after the decimal'''
   ...:     before, after = str(x).split('.')
   ...:     return int(before), (int(after)*10 if len(after)==1 else int(after))
   ...: 
   ...: 

In [5]: split_float(105.10)
Out[5]: (105, 10)

In [6]: split_float(105.01)
Out[6]: (105, 1)

In [7]: split_float(105.12)
Out[7]: (105, 12)
```

Comment: what does this do for 0.000005?

Answer (score 3):

Another example using modf

```
from math import modf
number = 1.0124584

# [0] decimal, [1] integer
result = modf(number)
print(result[0])
# output = 0124584
print(result[1])
# output = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Float numbers are not stored in decimal (base10) format. Have a read through the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) on this to satisfy yourself why. Therefore, to get a base10 representation from a float is not advisable.

Now there are tools which allow storage of numeric data in decimal format. Below is an example using the `Decimal` library.

```
from decimal import *

x = Decimal('0.341343214124443151466')
str(x)[-2:] == '66'  # True

y = 0.341343214124443151466
str(y)[-2:] == '66'  # False
```

Answer (score 2):

Easier if the input is a string, we can use split()

```
decimal = input("Input decimal number: ") #123.456

# split 123.456 by dot = ['123', '456']
after_coma = decimal.split('.')[1] 

# because only index 1 is taken then '456'
print(after_coma) # '456'
```

if you want to make a number type
print(int(after_coma)) # 456

Answer (score 2):

```py
a = 12.587
b = float('0.' + str(a).split('.')[-1])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Look this:

```py
>>> n = 5.55
>>> dec = int(str(n).split('.')[1])
>>> dec
55
>>> dec/(10**len(str(dec)))
0.55
```

---

As functions, if you want 0.55 (as a float number):

```py
def decimal_part(n:float) -> float:
    dec = int(str(n).split('.')[1])
    return dec/(10**len(str(dec)))
```

And if you want only 55 (as an integer):

```py
def decimal_part(n:float) -> int:
    return int(str(n).split('.')[1])
```

---

You can also add `n = float(n) if type(n)==int else n` in the first line of your `decimal_part` function if you are not sure if it will be a float or an integer which will be passed as an argument to the function, and if you want to keep the sign if n is negative (-5.55 give -0.55), try this:

```py
def decimal_part(n:float) -> float:
    n = float(n) if type(n)==int else n
    dec = int(str(n).split('.')[1])
    if n>=0:
        return dec/(10**len(str(dec)))
    return -dec/(10**len(str(dec)))
```

Let's give a try:

```py
>>> decimal_part(-5.55)
-0.55
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: probably the community bot asks to tell us a little about string slicing

Answer (score 1):

Use floor and subtract the result from the original number:

```
>> import math #gives you floor.
>> t = 5.55 #Give a variable 5.55
>> x = math.floor(t) #floor returns t rounded down to 5..
>> z = t - x #z = 5.55 - 5 = 0.55
```

Comment: If you're going to `import math`, why not just use `math.modf()`?

Comment: @ire_and_curses: I am providing an alternative solution to the problem.

Comment: floor does the same as casting to a int so could replace math.floor(t) with int(t)

Comment: @QuantumKarl No, they are different. `math.floor(-1.1) == -2` but `int(-1.1) == -1`. Though for this question using `int` is more correct.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
import math
x = 5.55
print((math.floor(x*100)%100))
```

This is will give you two numbers after the decimal point, 55 from that example. If you need one number you reduce by 10 the above calculations or increase depending on how many numbers you want after the decimal.

Comment: This is nice because it return a non-fractional value, but will break on negative numbers

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work most of the time. @Meow

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

x = 1245342664.6
print( (math.floor(x*1000)%1000) //100 )
```

It definitely worked

Comment: what does the operator // mean?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use the `re` module with `re.findall` or `re.search`:

```
import re


def get_decimcal(n: float) -> float:
    return float(re.search(r'\.\d+', str(n)).group(0))


def get_decimcal_2(n: float) -> float:
    return float(re.findall(r'\.\d+', str(n))[0])


def get_int(n: float) -> int:
    return int(n)


print(get_decimcal(5.55))
print(get_decimcal_2(5.55))
print(get_int(5.55))
```

#### Output

```
0.55
0.55
5
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/HcCnEL/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/HcCnEL/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### Source

[How to get rid of additional floating numbers in python subtraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58687240/how-to-get-rid-of-additional-floating-numbers-in-python-subtraction/58687387#58687387)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```py
number = 5.55
int(str(number).split('.')[1])
```

Comment: This is the real solution

Comment: float("0."+str(number).split('.')[1])

Answer (score 1):

This is only if you want toget the first decimal

```
print(int(float(input()) * 10) % 10)
```

Or you can try this

```
num = float(input())
b = num - int(num) 
c = b * 10
print(int(c))
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Using math module

speed of this has to be tested

```py
from math import floor

def get_decimal(number):
    '''returns number - floor of number'''
    return number-floor(number)
```

---

Example:

```
n = 765.126357123

get_decimal(n)
```

> 0.12635712300004798

Comment: Can test the speed with:
```from timeit import timeit
  
iterations = 1000000
result = timeit(
    'n = 765.126357123; x = n -floor(n)', 
    'from math import floor', 
    number=iterations
)
print("Total time was:", result)
print("Time per iterations was:", result/iterations)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def fractional_part(numerator, denominator):
    # Operate with numerator and denominator to 
# keep just the fractional part of the quotient
if  denominator == 0:
      return 0
  else:
       return (numerator/ denominator)-(numerator // denominator)  
 

print(fractional_part(5, 5)) # Should be 0
print(fractional_part(5, 4)) # Should be 0.25
print(fractional_part(5, 3)) # Should be 0.66...
print(fractional_part(5, 2)) # Should be 0.5
print(fractional_part(5, 0)) # Should be 0
print(fractional_part(0, 5)) # Should be 0
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
a = 1.234
b = a - int(a)
length = len(str(a))

round(b, length-2)
```

Output:
`print(b)`
`0.23399999999999999`
`round(b, length-2)`
`0.234`

Since the round is sent to a the length of the string of decimals ('0.234'), we can just minus 2 to not count the '0.', and figure out the desired number of decimal points. This should work most times, unless you have lots of decimal places and the rounding error when calculating b interferes with the second parameter of round.

Comment: Any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

```
your_num = 5.55
n = len(str(int(your_num)))
float('0' + str(your_num)[n:])
```

It will return `0.55`.

Answer (score 0):

```
number=5.55
decimal=(number-int(number))
decimal_1=round(decimal,2)
print(decimal)
print(decimal_1)
```

output: 0.55

Answer (score 0):

See what I often do to obtain numbers after the decimal point in python
   3:

```
a=1.22
dec=str(a).split('.')
dec= int(dec[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas:

```
df['decimals'] = df['original_number'].mod(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that really large numbers with really large fractional parts can cause problems when using modulo 1 to get the fraction.

```py
import decimal

>>> d = decimal.Context(decimal.MAX_PREC).create_decimal(
... '143000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.1231200000000000000002013210000000'
... )
...
>>> d % 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.DivisionImpossible'>]
```

I instead grabbed the integral part and subtracted it first to help simplify the rest of it.

```py
>>> d - d.to_integral()
Decimal('0.1231200000000000000002013210')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fractional_part(numerator, denominator):
    if denominator == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return numerator / denominator - numerator // denominator

print(fractional_part(5, 5)) # Should be 0
print(fractional_part(5, 4)) # Should be 0.25
print(fractional_part(5, 3)) # Should be 0.66...
print(fractional_part(5, 2)) # Should be 0.5
print(fractional_part(5, 0)) # Should be 0
print(fractional_part(0, 5)) # Should be 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Late in the party, leaving comment for new visitors.
If you know you need only 2 decimal places then you can use inbound round

```
round(1.15 % 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of the other solutions but none of them work for me.

In my case, I have different operations and always in the last step, my result has more than the expected decimals.

For example, if you do:

**61 * 0.1** the result is the float **6.1000000000000005**

To get the **6.1** we have to parse the default float (at least in my case with 64bits) to a lower one:

```
import numpy as np    

x = 61 * 0.1
y = np.float32(x)
```

If you have a lot of operations before, try to do the casting at the end :)

To answer better the original questions it would be:

```
import math
import numpy as np    

x_deci, x_inte = math.modf(5.55)
decimals = np.float32(x_deci)
```

and the result for the decimals is **0.55** instead of **0.5499999999999998**

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in the relative timing of the more sensible answers given here. Using this script on my laptop (MacBookPro16, 6-Core Intel Core i7 2.6 GHz):

```
#!/bin/sh

python3 -V
python3 -m timeit -s 'a = 5.55' 'b = a % 1'
python3 -m timeit -s 'a = 5.55' 'b = a - a//1'
python3 -m timeit -s 'a = 5.55; import math' 'b = a - math.floor(a)'
python3 -m timeit -s 'a = 5.55' 'b = a - int(a)'
python3 -m timeit -s 'a = 5.55; import math' 'frac, whole = math.modf(a)'
```

I get the following timing:

```
Python 3.9.10
10000000 loops, best of 5: 34.9 nsec per loop
5000000 loops,  best of 5: 51   nsec per loop
5000000 loops,  best of 5: 69.2 nsec per loop
5000000 loops,  best of 5: 84.1 nsec per loop
5000000 loops,  best of 5: 97.7 nsec per loop
```

So the simple `% 1` seems the fastest approach

Answer (score 0):

Try this def fuction

```
def decimales(n):
  n_int = int(n)
  n_int_len = len(int(str(n)))
  n_float = float(n)
  n_float_len = len(float(str(n)))
  n_decimal = n_float - n_int
  n_decimal_len = n_float_len - n_int_len
  n_decimal = round(n_decimal, n_decimal_len)
  return n_decimal
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76330061/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

A solution is using modulo and rounding.

```
import math

num = math.fabs(float(5.55))
rem = num % 1

rnd_by =   len(str(num)) - len(str(int(num))) - 1

print(str(round(rem,rnd_by)))
```

Your output will be 0.55

Answer (score -2):

Another crazy solution is (without converting in a string):

```
number = 123.456
temp = 1

while (number*temp)%10 != 0:
    temp = temp *10
    print temp
    print number

temp = temp /10
number = number*temp
number_final = number%temp
print number_final
```