# How to add a dot in python list

Tags: python

How do I add a dot into a Python list?

For example

```
 groups = [0.122, 0.1212, 0.2112]
```

If I want to output this data, how would I make it so it is like

```
122, 1212, 2112
```

I tried write(groups...[0]) and further research but didn't get far. Thanks.

Thankyou

Comment: You mean you want to find the decimal portion of the floating point numbers in your list?

Comment: @user3511074 Then you should edit your question to make it more accurate and descriptive... And while you're on it, take a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886402/python-how-to-get-numbers-after-decimal-point

Answer (score 2):

```
[str(g).split(".")[1] for g in groups]
```

results in

```
['122', '1212', '2112']
```

**Edit:**

Use it like this:

```
groups = [0.122, 0.1212, 0.2112]
decimals = [str(g).split(".")[1] for g in groups]
```

Comment: @PascalvKooten True, but there aren't any in the question.

Comment: Sorry to sound stupid but where would I put this in my overall code?

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: So yea, you most likely have a number which does not have a decimal point in it. It will also ignore anything *before* the decimals...

Comment: @user3511074 Please edit your question to include a sample of all the possible input data. Then I can extend my answer to work for all kind of input.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
groups = [0.122, 0.1212, 0.2112]
import re
groups_str = ", ".join([str(x) for x in groups])
re.sub('[0-9]*[.]', "", groups_str)
```

- `[str(x) for x in groups]` will make strings of the items.
- `", ".join` will connect the items, as a string.

`import re` allows you to replace regular expressions:

- using `re.sub`, the regular expression is used by replacing any numbers followed by a dot by nothing.

### EDIT (no extra modules):

Working with Lutz' answer, this will also work in the case there is an integer (no dot):

```
decimals = [str(g).split("0.") for g in groups]
decimals = decimals = [i for x in decimals for i in x if i != '']
```

It won't work though when you have numbers like `11.11`, where there is a part you don't want to ignore in front of the dot.

Comment: It's not even a string.

Comment: I don't know, regex sounds like an overkill here. My vote goes to Lutz

Comment: I am "not allowed" to import from anything other than Turtle.

Comment: Lutz has a much better answer given all items are floats!

Comment: @user3511074 This might bring you closer to your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension and return a list of strings

```
groups = [0.122, 0.1212, 0.2112]
[str(x).split(".")[1] for x in groups]
```

Result

```
['122', '1212', '2112']
```

The list comprehension is doing the following:

> - Turn each list element into a string
> - Split the string about the "." character
> - Return the substring to the right of the split
> - Return a list based on the above logic

Comment: Seems like copying Lutz' answer?

Comment: @PascalvKooten ... I always seem to be a day late and a dollar short on this site! By the time I finish typing and formatting my answer, people tend to beat me to the point.

Comment: The general advice is to upload an answer that is correct, and then edit it to add the explanation. Might help you!