# Get the fractional part of a float number in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I've the template as follows：

```
<h2>Coupon<b class="font40">{{ coupon.cash|floatformat:"0" }}</b>.00</h2>
```

I can get the integer part with 'floatformat'. How can I get the fractional part with Django template? （e.g. the fractional part of '8.5' is '5'） Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best choice is to create your own [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/), or to reduce processing in your templates, calculate the remainder in the view and pass it to the template as a specific field?

Theres a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886402/python-how-to-get-numbers-after-decimal-point) with some methods for the actual extraction of the digits within your filter (if you choose that method).