# How to get last 3 digits after comma?

Tags: python, regex

For a number that is 32,146 ...how do I find only 146? Is this able to be done?

```
findnum = '32,146'
return findnum
```

Comment: `findnum.split(",")[-1]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: how to get numbers after decimal point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886402/python-how-to-get-numbers-after-decimal-point)

Comment: it's a string. find the comma, then substring everything after it.

Answer (score 4):

Work with `split`

```
>>> findnum = '32,146'
>>> findnum.split(',')
['32', '146']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number you can do:

```
# get number by ignoring commas
number = int(findnum.replace(',',''))

# get last three digits
last_three = number % 1000
```

This will result in `146` (int) and not `'146'` (string)

Example:

```
>>> findnum = '32,146'
>>> number = int(findnum.replace(',',''))
>>> number % 1000
146
```

Comment: why not just `int(findnum[-3:]) % 1000`?

Answer (score -1):

Since its a string and not a number:

Can use slicing after the ',' to the end:

```
s[s.index(',')+1:]
```

Comment: `s = '1,000,000'` `s[s.index(',')+1:]` results in '000,000'