# How can I pass the selective part of fraction number to string for displaying?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, digits, fractions

I would like to display the first 4 digit of fraction number and pass it to string to display in title of my plot. I checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886402/how-to-get-numbers-after-decimal-point) but I couldn't find an elegant way.

I've tried following code as the easiest way the problem is I don't want to display `%` after that:

```py
train_MSE=mean_squared_error(Y_train, Y_RNN_Train_pred)
print("Train MSE:",train_MSE_)
#Train MSE: 0.33068236552127656

train_MSE_ = "%.4f%%" % train_MSE
print("Train MSE:",train_MSE_)
#Train MSE: 0.3307% 
#expected result without '%' ---> 0.337

plt.plot(Y_RNN_Test_pred[0],'b-')
plt.title(f'Test MSE={test_MSE_}', fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `%%` at the end.

```
train_MSE_ = "%.4f" % train_MSE_
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use the format command

```
print('{0:.4f}'.format(0.264875464))
```

result

```
0.2649
```

So you may write your code like:

```
train_MSE_=0.264875464
print('Train MSE:{0:.4f}'.format(train_MSE_))
```

reslut

```
Train MSE:0.2649
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
print("Train MSE : {:.4f}".format(train_MSE_))
```

You can see more details about format string here : https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#formatstrings