# How to convert float to integer strictly, without rounding?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wish to find a way to achieve the following: With the likes of 5.0, return 5. With the likes of 5.1, which cannot equal any integer, return Error.

Currently I use int() together with an "if integer != float". However this has problems, for instance I won't be able to tell whether the inequality was caused by the likes of 5.1 or the likes of 1111111111111111.0(and even larger numbers).

Also this is extremely troublesome compared with a potential, simple, one-line command. So is there a command in Python that does this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Float objects in Python have an `is_integer()` predicate.

```
def strict_int(x):
    if x.is_integer():
        return int(x)
    raise ValueError
```

Note that `int` objects do *not* have this method. You'll get an attribute error if you try to call this on an int.

---

If you wanted some error value instead of an exception, you can use a one-liner like this

```
int(x) if x.is_integer() else 'Error'
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `math` as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23702755/2906838) by [@Anthony V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3235741/anthony-v) like this:

```
>>> frac, whole = math.modf(5.0) 
>>> if frac ==0.0:
...     print("this is a whole") 
... else: 
...     print("this is not whole and should return the Error")
```

This should work easily.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether there's a more idiomatic way to do this, but intuitively, you can just compare the value of the `int` and the `float` and return only when they are equal.

That is

```
def weird_cast(my_float):
    if int(my_float) == my_float:
        return int(my_float)
    return None # or some error
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def return_int(a):
    if int(a)==a:
        print(int(a)) #you can store the integer value in separate variable #also b = int(a)
        #instead of using print you can use return b or int(a)   
    else:
        print('Error') #or you can use return 'Error'

a = 5.0
return_int(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another easier way is to minus with the round down number with itself.
if the remainder is more than 0.0 and less than 1.0, then we can call it a float otherwise integer

```
def IntegerSanityCheck ( num ):
    remainder = abs ( round ( num ) - num )
    if ( remainder > 0.0 ) and ( remainder < 1.0 ):
        print "Float"
    else:
        print "Integer"
```

or you can use `math` as suggested by user2906838