# How to get rid of additional floating numbers in python subtraction?

Tags: python, subtraction, floating

```
def function():
    n=123.456
    x=int(n)
    y=n-int(n)
    print(x,y)
```

result:

```
x= 123
y= 0.45600000000000307
```

how to get exactly `.456` without using library function,
`n` can be any floating number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: it is natural for float numbers. You can try with standard module `decimal` if you need precise values -  `d = decimal.Decimal('123.456')` `print(d - int(d))`

Answer (score 1):

If you know from the outset that the number of decimal places is 3, then:

```
y = round(n - int(n), 3)
```

If you *don't* know the number of decimal places, then you can work it out, as so:

```
y = round(n - int(n), str(n)[::-1].find('.'))
```

As furas pointed out, you can also use the `decimal` package:

```
from decimal import Decimal

n = Decimal('123.456') 
y = n - int(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `re` module:

```
import re

def get_decimcal(n: float) -> float:
    return float(re.search(r'\.\d+', str(n)).group(0))

def get_decimcal_2(n: float) -> float:
    return float(re.findall(r'\.\d+', str(n))[0])

def get_int(n: float) -> int:
    return int(n)


print(get_decimcal(123.456))
print(get_decimcal_2(123.456))
print(get_int(123.456))
```

#### Output

```
0.456
0.456
123
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `round(y,n)`, and `n=3` its the numbers of decimals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%f` to round of the floating value to required digits.

```
def function(n):

    x = int(n)
    y = n-int(n)
    print(x,"%.2f" % y)

function(123.456)
```

Output:

```
123

0.456
```