# Get value to the right of the decimal in python

Tags: python

If I print 5/4 I get 1.25. How do I just get the .25 part.

```
print(5/4)
1.25
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get numbers after decimal point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886402/how-to-get-numbers-after-decimal-point)

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem -- what are you actually trying to do? It's almost certainly not to get the number to the right of the decimal (which would be `25`)

Comment: Can you use `5/4 % 1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution but this will work

```
print(5/4-5//4)
```