# Python digits after decimal to be given as output

Tags: python, list, types

For the value

```
x=1.48759
```

I want output as

```
48759
```

example 2:

```
x=1.92345
```

output:

```
92345
```

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. Stackoverflow isn't a community where people are supposed to give you finished solution. They are there to help you troubleshoot and to guide you. You can turn those values into a string `str()` and then use `split(".")`. You'll get an array of strings and in one part you will find your desired output.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886402/how-to-get-numbers-after-decimal-point

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I got it how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` for this case:

```
number = 1.49921
int(re.findall(r'\.(.*)',str(number))[0])
```

Outputs:

```
49921
```