# How to return the fractional part of a number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I get the fractional part of a number?

For example,  I have a list of floats `num = [12.73, 9.45]` and want to get only the numbers after the decimal point, `73` and `45` in this case. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Perhaps make the values a string and call `.split('.')`?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: This website is no substitute for reading one of the (huge!) number of Python language tutorials available,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get numbers after decimal point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886402/how-to-get-numbers-after-decimal-point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
num = [12.73, 9.45];
result = list(map(lambda x: int(str(x).split('.')[1]),num))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 5):

One approach is using pure(ish) maths.

#### The short answer:

```
num = [12.73, 9.45]

[int((f % 1)*100) for f in num]

>>> [73, 44]
```

#### Explanation:

The [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) returns the remainder once whole division is complete (to over-simplify).

Therefore this, returns the decimal value; the fractional part of the number.

```
12.73 % 1

>>> 0.7300000000000004
```

To get the decimal value as a integer, you can use:

```
int((12.73 % 1)*100)

>>> 73
```

Just wrap this in a loop for all required values ... and you have the 'short answer' above.

Comment: Thank for the help.

Comment: My pleasure - hope it makes sense.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

> and want to get only the numbers after the period,

There is no such thing. Numbers *don't have* digits; the *string representation of* the numbers has digits. And even then, floating-point numbers are *not precise*; you may be shown `0.3` in one context and [`0.30000000000000004`](https://0.30000000000000004.com/) in another, *for the same value*.

It sounds like what you are actually after is the [*fractional part of*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) the numbers. There are many ways to do this, but they all boil down the same idea: it is the result when you divide (as a floating-point number) the input by 1.

For a single value, it looks like:

```
fractional_part = value % 1.0
```

or

```
# This built-in function performs the division and gives you
# both quotient and remainder.
integer_part, fractional_part = divmod(value, 1.0)
```

or

```
import math
fractional_part = math.fmod(value, 1.0)
```

or

```
import math
# This function is provided as a special case.
# It also gives you the integer part.
# Notice that the results are the other way around vs. divmod!
fractional_part, integer_part = math.modf(value)
```

To process each value in a list in the same way, use a [list comprehension](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/).