# Is there a way to print only the decimal part?

Tags: python

I'm having a hard time doing this I have tried experimenting with (0:.2f)
I want the program to only print the decimal part
Example inputs and outputs

Inputs
100.56
455.345
89.5

Outputs
.56
.345
.5

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you may try the code as below

```
input = 100.56
print(input % 1)
```

you could refer to the answer at [How to get numbers after decimal point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886402/how-to-get-numbers-after-decimal-point)

Comment: Try to avoid use `input` built-in function as your variable name.

Comment: that was just an example. but yea input as a variable name is not a good idea though. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only the original decimal part, you can do :

```
inputFloat = 25189456.1584566
decimalPart = '.' + str(inputFloat).split('.')[1]
print(decimalPart)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
def f(x, decimals=2):
    r = str(round(x, decimals)) #round and convert to string
    r = r.split('.')[-1] #split at the dot and keep the decimals
    r = '.' + r #add the dot
    return r

f(100.56789) #.57

[f(x) for x in [100.56, 455.345, 89.5]] #['.56', '.35', '.5']
```

The one-liner would be `'.' + str(round(x, 2)).split('.')[-1]`  or `f".{str(round(x, 2)).split('.')[-1]}"` where `x` is the float you are interested in.