# How to plot a triangular wave using a piecewise function in Python?

Tags: python

I am currently taking my first Python coding course and I am very stuck on this assignment.
The goal is to define a function 'F(t)' using a piecewise function that would make a graph of a triangle wave that looks identical to:

[image]

This is what I have tried:

```
def F(t):
 if (t >= 0) & (t <= 1/2):
  return 4*t
elif (t >= 1/2) & (t < 1):
 return -4*t
else:
 return 0

f = np.vectorize(F)
t = np.linspace(0,4,num=8)
plt.plot(t,f(t))
```

Obviously, to no luck. The above code matches the ideal graph from 0 to 1 so I'm really just struggling with how to make the graph a continuous triangle wave for all t > 0.

Any tips or suggestions are much appreciated

Comment: Well instead of `else: return 0`, your function could return some actual values for `t >= 1`.

Comment: If your function works well for 0<t<1, I'd play with `a%b` and `numpy.mod(a,b)` to scale any value t>1 down to a value 0<t<1

Comment: Ill try that, thanks!

Comment: Your function seems to go from 1 to -1 in the range [0, .5], so it looks like your function there is 1 - 4 * 5.  From .5 to 1, it looks like F(t) = 4 * t - 3.  The first line of your code should be t = t % 1.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables in `F()`. At this moment it gets `t` like `0.5714285714285714` or `1.1428571428571428` but if you would use `num=9` then you would get exactly `0.5`, `1.0`

Answer (score 2):

Your function is wrong. If you want the troughs to be at odd multiples of `0.5` and the peaks to be at even multiples of `0.5`, and you want the value to be `1` and `-1`, your function needs to be `-4 * t + 1` between `0` and `0.5`, and `4 * t - 3` between `0.5` and `1`.

Also, your function returns `0` for `t < 0` and for `t > 1`, so your output doesn't match the expected output outside those bounds.

Since your `if` conditions describe the correct behavior when you have only the part of the input *after the decimal point*, you can [extract that part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886402/how-to-get-numbers-after-decimal-point) and use it instead of `t`:

```
def F(t):
    decimal_part = t % 1
    if 0 <= decimal_part <= 0.5:
        return -4*decimal_part + 1
    else:
        return 4*decimal_part - 3
```

Which gives this:

[image: Expected plot]

Remember to discretize the x-axis so it has enough points. I plotted the blue line with `t = np.linspace(0, 4, 1000)`, and the red line with `t = np.linspace(0, 4, 10)` and everything else remained the same.

The `np.vectorize()` function doesn't *really* vectorize a function though. If you want to actually see speed improvements, you're going to have to vectorize the function yourself by expressing its logic as a vector operation.

```
def g(t):
    dec = (t % 1) - 0.5
    return (np.abs(dec) - 0.25) * 4
```

Both give the same plots, but timing the execution shows the difference:

```
import timeit

t1 = timeit.timeit('f(t)', setup='from __main__ import np, f, t', number=10000)
t2 = timeit.timeit('g(t)', setup='from __main__ import np, g, t', number=10000)

# t1 = 3.322270042001037
# t2 = 0.17450489799375646

print(t1 / t2)
# 19.038262422410074
```

The *actually* vectorized function is ~19x faster on my computer (Intel Python 3.7 with numpy+MKL on Macbook Air)

Answer (score 0):

First you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables.

In `F()` you get `t` like `0.5714285714285714`, `1.1428571428571428` but if you would use `num=9` instead of `num=8` then you would get exactly `0.5`, `1.0` and it would be much easier to draw it.

And using `print()` to display results for different combinations I created

```
def F(t):
    return 1 - ((t*2) % 2)
```

Which can be reduced to

```
def F(t):
    return 1 - (t % 1)
```

---

How I get it:

You have `y` in range (-1, 1) which gives length `2` so I started with `y = t % 2` to get values in range (0, 2) which also gives length `2`. Because for `0` I got `0` and I needed `1` so next I used `1 - ...` to get a "mirror image". So I get y=1 for x=0 but next top was for y=2 but I needed for y=1 so I had to use `*2` to get it. And finally I released that `(t*2) % 2` can be `(t % 2) * (2 % 2)` so it gives `(t % 2) * 1` and this gives `(t % 2)`

---

Minimal working code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def F(t):
    #y = t % 2
    #y = 1 - (t % 2)
    #y = 1 - ((t*2) % 2)
    y = 1 - (t % 1)
    print(t, y)
    return y

f = np.vectorize(F)
t = np.linspace(0, 4, num=9)
plt.plot(t, f(t))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Changing the num pts in `linspace` to `9` actually _hides_ an issue with OP's code: Those lines aren't +/-4*t

Comment: @PranavHosangadi yes, this is problem for values differen then `num=9` but frankly OP didn't say it has to use `num=8` or that it has to work for every `num`. So I decided to mak this modification.

Comment: Also your function gives me this with 1000 points: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOyP5.png

Comment: Re. _"frankly OP didn't say it has to use num=8"_ Well OP said they need to reproduce the triangular wave. That would seem to indicate they want it to give the correct values for _all_ values of `t`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi let OP decide if code has to work for every `num` or it can work only for `num=9`