# From a list of floats, how to keep only mantissa in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I have a list of numbers from which I'd like to return a list of mantissas:

```
get_mantissa([1.565888, 2.073744, 2.962492, 4.52838, 5.417127, 7.025337])
#[0.565888, 0.073744, 0.962492, 0.52838, 0.417127, 0.025337]
```

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not called mantissa, which is [normally used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand) for floating point numbers after normalizing with the exponent, i.e. the mantissa of 11.23 is 1.123. The thing you ask for I would simply call the fractional part.

Comment: possible duplicate of [in python, how do i split a number by the decimal point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454085/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-number-by-the-decimal-point)

Comment: @BasSwinckels My usage of the word is referenced from WolframMathWorld:http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mantissa.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take all your numbers mod 1:

```
>>> l = [1.565888, 2.073744, 2.962492, 4.52838, 5.417127, 7.025337]
>>> 
>>> [a%1 for a in l]
[0.565888, 0.07374400000000003, 0.9624920000000001, 0.5283800000000003, 0.4171269999999998, 0.025337000000000387]
```

If you will be dealing with negatives as well, then `a - int(a)` should do it:

```
>>> [a - int(a) for a in l]  # works with negatives too
[0.565888, 0.07374400000000003, 0.9624920000000001, 0.5283800000000003, 0.4171269999999998, 0.025337000000000387]
```

Comment: Ah, very clever! I was immediately tending towards regex, but this is very good :). Thank you.

Comment: @JoeyDiNardo a regex is tool for working with strings. a for manipulating strings. When dealing with numbers, in most cases, you would use math.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to do it using numpy. Also something to consider is how negative numbers should be treated.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1.234, 5.678, -9.012])

print a % 1
# [ 0.234  0.678  0.988]

print a % np.sign(a)
# [ 0.234  0.678 -0.012]
```

Answer (score 3):

In numpy you have [`np.modf`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.modf.html) that does a little more than you want:

```
>>> np.modf([1.565888, 2.073744, 2.962492, 4.52838, 5.417127, 7.025337])
(array([ 0.565888,  0.073744,  0.962492,  0.52838 ,  0.417127,  0.025337]),
 array([ 1.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  5.,  7.]))
```

So this will give you your desired result:

```
>>> np.modf([1.565888, 2.073744, 2.962492, 4.52838, 5.417127, 7.025337])[0]
array([ 0.565888,  0.073744,  0.962492,  0.52838 ,  0.417127,  0.025337])
```